How to rank 10 Year Average of Income Per Capita of various countries in Dataframe?
I know how to rank countries by their Income Per Capita for each individual year but I want to know how to rank the 10 Year Median of their Per Capita Incomes so for instance in 1950s I compare the 10 Year Median of Income Per Capita of Various Countries which are having Income Data starting from 1950.
The reason why I want to do is to reduce the impact of Currency Volatility on the Income Data as it is converted from local currencies using Market Exchange Rates. There is a issue with this in that the sample of countries which are having Income Data are not constant (i.e. in 1950 there is 55 countries having Income Per Capita Data whereas in 1959 there is 75 countries).
Considering I want to take a 10 Year Median of Income Per Capita for each country in each Decade I would like to only rank the countries having Income Data from the start of each Decade (so for 1950s take the 10 Year Median of only countries having Income Data from the year 1950 and rank these 10 Year Medians in Descending Order such that the richest country for that decade is at top and poorest country for that decade at bottom. Same for 1960s,1970s,etc).
Below is the code that I use to rank countries by their Income Per Capita for each individual year.
Thanks,
Anon.
install.packages("pwt10","dplyr")
library(pwt10)
data(pwt10.01)
library(dplyr)

PWT1950_2019 <-
    pwt10.01 |>
    filter(i_cig %in% c("ICPPPP-benchmark+interpolated","ICPPPP-extrapolated","benchmark","extrapolated","interpolated")) |>
 mutate(PL_CON= pl_con/pl_con[isocode=="USA"], .by=year) |>
 mutate(Income= ccon*PL_CON/pop, .by=year) |>
 mutate(IncomeRank= percent_rank(Income), .by= year) |>

View(PWT1950_2019 |> select(c("country","isocode","year","Income","IncomeRank")))

Image of the resulting Dataframe

Here's an approach where I label the decade, calculate the country median per decade (I do this first in case you later wanted the flexibility to include countries with, say, 9 or 10 years of decade data), and filter to include only countries with full decades.
At this point you could either join this data to a version of itself where you've calculated the summary ranking among country-decades, or in this case I nest all the other data so we can get to one row per country-decade, allowing us to do the percent_rank calculation in the same pipe. Then we unnest and voila.
pwt10.01 |>
  filter(i_cig %in% c("ICPPPP-benchmark+interpolated","ICPPPP-extrapolated","benchmark","extrapolated","interpolated")) |>
  mutate(PL_CON= pl_con/pl_con[isocode=="USA"], .by=year) |>
  mutate(Income= ccon*PL_CON/pop, .by=year) |>
 
  # calc decade, income median/decade, and keep full decades only
  mutate(decade = floor(year/10)*10) |>
  mutate(Income_median = median(Income), .by = c(country, decade)) |>
  filter(n() == 10, .by = c(country, decade)) |>

  # nest, rank, unnest
  tidyr::nest(data = -c(country, decade, Income_median)) |>
  mutate(IncomeRank = percent_rank(Income_median), .by = decade) |>
  tidyr::unnest(data)

We could alternatively save the data after the filter step, e.g. -> temp, then:
temp |>
  left_join(temp |>
              distinct(country, decade, Income_median) |>  
              mutate(IncomeRank = percent_rank(Income_median), .by = decade))

Or we could accomplish the same thing in-pipe, but from approaches I've seen so far, it gets a little unwieldy with {}'s and different syntax for the magrittr pipe %>% vs. the base R pipe |>. For example, Using rbind within a pipe
